# How to show loading icon in react native until the API response in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am creating a new app. After tapping the submit button I want to show the loading icon in the login page  until the API response. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

First create a state variable for showing and hiding loader as follows

```
this.state = {
..
loading: false, 
..
};
```

In the api call before the request send, you can set loading state to true and after completing the response set it to false

```
getData() {

  this.setState({loading:true});// For showing loader
  axios.get('api_link_goes_here')
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({loading:false});// For hiding loader
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.setState({loading:false});// For hiding loader
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

In your render template, you can add a View for showing the loader based on the state, You can add it to the bottom and position and make it full screen to avoid further clicks until response is received

```
render() {
    return (
<View style={container}> 
.....

{this.state.loading === true &&
  <View style={styles.myloader}>
    <CustomLoader /> // You can define this in another component or simply write <Text>Please wait...</Text>
  </View>
}

....
</View> 
)}
```

Style is given below for loader container

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
.....

    myloader: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        zIndex: 10,
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        opacity: 0.9,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%"
    }

...
});
```

Comment: Different variation for this you can try,It is up to you based on the design , The above code is a custom method which I had used in one my project. Try different if you can...  All the best  :)